# Uploadify never executing upload script

Tags: javascript, io, uploadify, ioerror

I'm having problems with uploadify and uploading files. The script that does the actual uploading via PHP never seems to get executed and I can't figure out why. The script that checks if a file exists executes, but the upload script won't.

Uploadify is throwing an IO Error when trying to upload

Here's my uploadify declaration: (ignore simple syntax errors, i manually typed this)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#file_upload').uploadify({

    'uploader'   : 'javascript/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'     : 'javascript/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg'  : 'javascript/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'checkScript': 'javascript/uploadify/check.php',
    'folder'     : '', // Hard coded in php file for security
    'auto'       : true,
    'multi'      : false,
    'simUploadLimit' : 1,
    'sizeLimit'  : 10000000,
    'fileExt'    : '*.txt',
    'fileDesc'   : '.TXT'
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of:**

```
  'script'     : 'javascript/uploadify/uploadify.php',
```

**Try:**

```
  'script'     : 'javascript/uploadify/uploadify.php?swf=1',
```